How to stream OpenCV output to browser like a ShoutCast in Python?
I'm trying to display video processed by OpenCV in a web browser similar to how ShoutCast does it. I know that ShoutCast somehow does it over HTTP protocol, but I don't know how to make it display both the video and have the page loaded, rather than constantly loading until the processing is complete. I also know that ShoutCast doesn't send anything to the stream page because when I launch developer tools, nothing is sent periodically, yet time keeps increasing and the music keeps playing continuously. Does anyone know how I could do this?
My Testing Code:
import os
from flask import Flask, Response
import cv2
from utils.app_root_dir import app_root_dir

app = Flask(__name__)


def generate_frames():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.normpath(app_root_dir().joinpath("data/temp", "video-979257305707693982.mp4")))
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video-stream')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame', status=None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True)


ShoutCast Streams used for Tests:
Stream #1
Stream #2

not with flask and not with opencv. neither is for video streaming. opencv is also not for audio. please learn how media content is streamed on the web. learn about all the involved technologies. flask is not one of them.

@ChristophRackwitz But after all, ShoutCast streams via the HTTP protocol. Even Wikipedia says so, or other websites. So what I should to do?

Because ShoutCast doesn't use HLS or RTMP, otherwise it would be stated that it uses those protocols. All I found was information that it uses the HTTP protocol.

I didn't say anything about HTTP though. I said flask is ill-suited to video streaming. I said you need to investigate the technologies further. learn about media containers. learn what data is transferred over HTTP when shoutcast does it. use wireshark to see what really happens. learn to interpret the data you see.

However, I need to use Flask and OpenCV because I'm developing a desktop application in Python with a Vue3 client for real-time crowd analysis and detection. Everything is almost ready except that I need to transmit processed video in real-time to display it in the Vue client.

@ChristophRackwitz says Flask is ill-suited to video streaming.  That's not really true.  Flask doesn't really know or care what you're sending to the client.  All that matters is that you can send things in a streaming sort of way, chunk by chunk.  Of course, Flask supports this using generators:  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/streaming/

I also know that ShoutCast doesn't send anything to the stream page because when I launch developer tools, nothing is sent periodically

No, that's not true.  Data is continuously streamed via a single HTTP connection.  The browser makes the request for the stream.  The server sends it, and doesn't stop.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Yeah, you'll want to start by using a video codec.  Right now you're just encoding frame after frame as JPEG.  That's not very efficient and doesn't work as-is.  You'll need a video codec such as VP9 or H.264 to take raw frame buffers and encode them into a stream.
Next, you'll need mux that stream into a container, such as WebM/Matroska, which will keep all the timing information and what not so that the player can actually playback the decoded frames.
Then, just serve that stream out of the muxer to the client on-demand.  No multipart, no none of that, just, the stream.
The easiest way to do all that is execute FFmpeg from your Python process.  Configure it to read raw frames in RGBA (or whatever you're getting from OpenCV), and then output the video.  Something like this...
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s:v 640x480 -r 30 -i - -c:v libvpx-vp9 -f matroska -

Then, just pipe the STDOUT from FFmpeg to the client.
On your client's web page, it's as simple as...
<video src="/video-stream" autoplay muted></video>


I've just done something similar in Python. Here's the code in the link, but it doesn't work as you say. (I tried using HLS in this case). https://pastebin.com/cUdiDbyH

@Tebyy HLS isn't going to work this way.  HLS is just a pile of static files... playlists and media segments that can be served by any web server.  By all means, if you need to serve a stream to a lot of people and may potentially use CDNs, HLS is the way to go.  But, if you want just a 1:1 low latency stream to monitor your OpenCV stuff, you need to use an FFmpeg output that actually outputs a stream.  And, there's no need to read it from disk... that's what the second - is for at the end... it outputs via STDOUT, which should be sent directly to the client as-is.

the trouble with flask comes when you expect it to work within an OpenCV loop that fetches video data. that will probably require threads, and passing data around, and knowing how flask's process model works in relation to client connections, and then you have to sequence all of this (start, run, stop) -- all the usual beginners show up with flask in hand, and expect to be able to "stream" their opencv code's operation with multipart-replace magic. things always fail in some way.

I assume that's what you were referring to. The issue is that although it doesn't throw any errors, the page loads indefinitely and doesn't display the stream. Code: https://pastebin.com/Z9Lv9xDj

@Tebyy What page?  You need a separate web page... this is only going to output video, not a web page.  You should have a static web page with a <video> element with its src attribute pointed at your stream URL.  If it still doesn't work, try outputting to a file on disk and testing it to ensure you're getting a good recording.

@Brad But I think what you wrote to me about what I should do is the steps to implement the functionality like ShoutCast has. It should work the same way, shouldn't it?

@Tebyy Yes, and to receive a SHOUTcast stream, you'd use an <audio> element.

However, when you access the ShoutCast stream address, the audio appears immediately, and you don't need to add any tags or wrap it in additional ones like you would with .

@Tebyy Depends on the browser.  Not all browsers automatically create this filler page for the audio stream.  I don't know what browser you're using or what would trigger it for your browser, but you might also want to check your Content-Type header, and ensure you have codecs in there too.  (Something like video/webm; codecs="vp9".  In the mean time, just make sure your stream is actually working... open that URL in VLC.  Set it up in a <video> tag.  Test with a file, as I mentioned before.

For now, I've set up saving to a file for testing purposes. My question is, how do I set the remaining parameters? Because, as you can notice in the console logs, not all parameters are being set, and some are set to "0", "N/A", or "unknown". FFMPEG code & logs: https://pastebin.com/MaxdbKBD

@Tebyy Ok, does your test file work?  In any case, you need to convert pixel format.  Try adding something like -pix_fmt yuv420p in your output parameters (before the last -, not before the first -).

Does that mean yuv420p is better than bgr24? Because I care about good stream quality.

@Tebyy No, of course not, this is about testing compatibility to figure out what the problem is.  If you care about good stream quality, why are you using just a couple megabit for a 1920x1080 image?  You should just experiment at this point and figure out what works and what tradeoffs you want to make.

I've set a higher bitrate and kept bgr24, but the bitrate and vbv_delay still aren't being set. Current settings: https://pastebin.com/UeYXCMc3

And all the parameters are in accordance with the documentation.
